# Foudation Zurb dynamic Reveal modal box

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I have a few items in a list, each item has a delete link, I want a reveal modal box shown when they press the delete button with a YES and Cancel link inside.

If the user presses the YES button the reveal modal should redirect to something like this:

www.url.com/delete/item_id

how could I pass the item_id to the Reveal modal box?

Foundation reveal modal box: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/reveal.php

Modal Box (item_id should be passed to modal box):

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal [expand, xlarge, large, medium, small]">
  <h2>Are you sure you want to delete this item?</h2>
  <a href="/delete/item_id">Yes</a>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Calling Reveal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#deleteItem").click(function() {
      $("#myModal").reveal();
    });
  });
</script>
```

HTML (item_id should be passed to modal):

```
<a href="item_id" class="button" data-reveal-id="myModal" id="deleteItem">Delete Item</a>
```

Comment: Do you have the HTMl and code?

Comment: I edited for you and put some of my code to make it more clear
@CR41G14

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the value using jQuery before the `.reveal();` is called

UPDATED:
See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgprU/

Html:

```
<ul id="deleteItem">
    <li><a href="10">Click Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="20">Click Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="30">Click Me</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
  <h2>Are you sure you want to delete <span id="targetName">error</span>?</h2>
  <a id="confirmDelete" href="setMe">Yes</a>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

​Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#deleteItem a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#confirmDelete").attr('href','/delete/' + target)
    $("#targetName").text(target);
    $("#myModal").reveal();
  });
});
```

​

Comment: This only passes the first HREF in my list and the value is always the value of the first HREF in the source code

Comment: Some how I missed the part about deleting from a list of items. I've updated the answer with a working example and new code.